# Remove trailing slash in canonical url for Magento home page

Tags: url, seo, canonical

For some reason my canonical url for the home page has a trailing slash. Why has Magento added this and how can I remove it?

Comment: Please do refer this,
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6314/internal-links-to-end-with-a-trailing-slash